# XSL "not" not working as expected attempting to compare two variables

Tags: xslt

Using XSL v3.0 I'm trying to compare two variables. One was created from .txt format directory listings imported as unparsed text. The other was created by querying xml files. Both contain references to jpgs.

I want to create a third variable using select="not" to find out which jpg references are present in one variable but not the other. I know the syntax for this `$var1[not(.=$var2)]` I was successfully able to do it in another place in this same XSL file.

I can output the values from each of the two variables and they look just like a .txt file would, and the values are what I would expect to see.

But for the life of me I cannot get the "not" to work. As far as I can tell it just returns the entire value of one of the variables.

Is there a way to just brute force these two variables into the same format so I can do this? I just want each variable to be a flat file that I can compare to the other and output another boring old flat file. I've tried all the combinations of tokenize and string-join etc. that I've stumbled across and nothing seems to work.

If I was using a bash script I would just pipe the dirs to two .txt files and use diff to do this, but achieving the same thing in XSL is killing me.

Clearly I am a novice at XSL. Any assistance appreciated.

per Michael Kay's suggestion
complete xsl available at this dropbox link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fsltr34f5l3ci5a/jpg_report_stack.xsl?dl=0

variable with all jpg names - $jpg_all_distinct_joined

```
<xsl:variable name="jpg_all_distinct_joined" as="xs:string" select="string-join((distinct-values(($token_full, $token_800, $token_thumb))),'&#10;')"/>
```

variable with all jpg references from xml - $jpg_all_links

```
<xsl:variable name="jpg_all_links" select="($jpg_link_pb, $jpg_link_bibl, $jpg_link_ref)"/>
```

not statement

```
<xsl:variable name="jpgs_in_xml_not_directories" select="($jpg_all_links)[not(.=$jpg_all_distinct_joined)]"/>
```

outputs the value of $jpg_all_links - this is not what I want - I want the output to be all jpg references from $jpg_all_links that are not in $jpg_all_distinct_joined

Comment: The best way forward would be to show us some code. Cut the problem down to its essentials, and show us your best attempt at a solution, indicating what output you want to get and how your actual output differs.

Comment: Here's a link to an anonymized version of the entire xsl file - it's too big to post here 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fsltr34f5l3ci5a/jpg_report_stack.xsl?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$jpg_all_links` is a sequence concatenation of the three variables `($jpg_link_pb, $jpg_link_bibl, $jpg_link_ref)`. All three of these variables are constructed using `string-join()` with newline as the separator, so it seems likely that `$jpg_all_links` is a sequence of three strings, each comprising multiple strings separated by newlines. The variable `$jpg_all_distinct_joined` is also formed using `string-join()` with a newline separator. So my suspicion is that (writing # to represent a newline character), you are doing something like

```
("A#B#C", "D#E#F")[not(. = "C#D")]
```

and nothing is being eliminated because none of the strings is equal to "C#D". You want to compare the sets of individual strings, not the composite strings formed using string-join().

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. Is there a way for me to change the variables $jpg_all_links and  $jpg_all_distinct_joined AFTER I've created them but before I do the "not" comparison to make this work? Something I can run them through to create two new variables that work?  I guess I'm looking for a way to consolidate those composite strings, not create them differently.

I need to compare the values the way that I am now.

Comment: Just keep the strings as a sequence instead of concatenating them using string-join?

Comment: I've gathered all the information I need to compare into two variables. Is it not possible in XSL to take that information and put it into two variables that can be compared? It's a computer. This doesn't seem like an unheard of "need to do". Just read everything from $var1_nested and put it into $var1_flat?

You're suggesting I bake a cake without eggs because the software won't let me put eggs in at the same time as flour.

Comment: I don't follow your analogies. I've suggested a way of doing it that works, and you're saying you'd like to do it a different way that doesn't work, and the different way ought to work because it's a computer after all?

Comment: Do you think driving people away from XSLT with your condescension and belittling bodes well for the future of Saxon? I know that after this particular exercise I hope to never have to deal with XSLT again.

Comment: I do a lot of work on the internet trying to help people. Many of them take my advice and make good progress. Some of them don't take my advice and...

Comment: Do you think that deriding those who give freely of their time to try and help you debug your code by accusing them of being condescending bodes well for your future as a programmer?